# Device max zoom in react natiive expo camera

Tags: react-native, camera, expo

My first question on stack overflow  ^_^

im using the **expo-camera** library ,  and want to get the max zoom that the mobile can do...

actually , what i need is to make a default zoom equals at maximum 2x ...

can any body help